# Changing sound and vibration for Notification Channel on Oreo 8.1

Tags: android

Officially sound and vibration for a Notification Channel are 
 "Only modifiable before the channel is submitted to
 `NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel)`."

But I saw now that when a go to Whatsapp settings and change the sound or vibration, those changes appear in the setting for the respective channel (Private or Group).

How can I do that? (I'm using android 8.1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whatsapp doesn't edit the channel, simply for any change you make they delete the channel and create a new one with the same name (with different id). I perceived now that every time you make changes the 'Deleted categories' count goes up.

Comment: but if the user had some settings for that ChannelId , if we delete and create with different ID with same name it will look same will the settings will be lost for that channel, is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this with adding sound and vibration in *notificationChannel***

For example:

```
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    String notifyID = "1003";
    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(notifyID, CHANNEL_ID, importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri, null);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    }
```

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: have you try this??? Create notification with this and go to your app settings>notification, where you get options like Whatsapp

Comment: Go to whatsapp and open the settings there, that is what the question is about, not how to create a channel.