# How to open notification channel sound settings(picker) directly (because channel sound cant be changed programatically) in android (kotlin)?

Tags: android

I've observed that WhatsApp allows users to change notification channel sounds by launching the system's sound picker. However, I've attempted to achieve this functionality using an intent to pick a sound, but I encountered a limitation in Android. Once a notification channel is created, users can't change its sound. Is there a workaround or alternative method to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

this is not the exact solution
but we can launch the sound picker and use this solution
​​https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316786/changing-sound-and-vibration-for-notification-channel-on-oreo-8-1
if you need to dynamically change the notification sound